# ProjectEuler - Largest Palindrome Product returning 0

Tags: java, palindrome

For some reason, the following code produces a 0 in the output and I do not know why.

```
    long i = 999;
    long j = 999;
    long pal = 0;
    for(; i >= 100; i--) { //Practice: 99 * 99
        for(; j >= 100; j--) {
            long k = i * j; // 9801 999*999 ~= 999006
            String normal = String.valueOf(k);//String(9801)
            String palindrome = new StringBuffer(normal).reverse().toString();//String(1089)
            if (normal.equals(palindrome)) { //False
                if (Long.valueOf(normal) > pal) { //Is greater than
                    pal = Long.valueOf(normal); // pal =
                }
            }
        }
    }
    System.out.println(pal);
```

Is it a problem with using StringBuffer or Strings? It DOES return an answer when the for() loops are set to i > 0, not i >= 100.

Comment: What are you expecting it to print?

Comment: maybe there's no palindrome found?

Comment: Isn't Long.valueOf(normal) not just k?

Comment: @shmosel the actual answer is in the 900k range

Comment: yes normal is k, I personally find it easier to keep it as a string

Comment: @RA3236 Specifically...?

Comment: I believe it was 909909 or something, my friend said the answer and as such I don't remember the exact value. The program is meant to find the largest palindrome product of two three digit numbers (aka 99 * 91 creates the largest palindrome where the inputs are two digit numbers) @shmosel

Comment: Make sure to tag your question correct. Otherwise all the palindrome experts on SO won't get notified :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`j` is not reset after `i` reaches 100. Move the initialization into the `for` statement, where it belongs:

```
for(long i = 999; i >= 100; i--) {
    for(long j = 999; j >= 100; j--) {
```

[Now it prints 906609.](https://ideone.com/spI5GU)

As a side note, use `Long.parseLong()` instead of `Long.valueOf()` to avoid unnecessary boxing and unboxing.

Comment: Ah that makes sense. I think I decided against doing that for some stupid reason. Thanks!

Comment: No problem. If this answered your question, please [accept it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work).